# Boost::log misbehaves (ubuntu 16.04, boost 1.58)

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

On my laptop any program compiled with `g++` and the `-std=c++14` flag that uses `boost::log` misbehaves (and can segfault in some cases). The simplest "working" example is the following:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main() {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Will it crash?";

    return 0;
}
```

Which can be compiled with

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -lboost_log -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lpthread
```

The output I get is

```
lorenzo@carbon:/tmp$ ./test 
[2018-03-02 23:22:10.324160] [0x00007f6ecb23c740] [info]
```

which lacks the log message. If I compile with `-g2` and run the program through valgrind I get the following error:

```
==7431== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7431==    at 0x53FFF8B: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==7431==    by 0x401AF6: boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::formatted_write(char const*, long) (formatting_ostream.hpp:556)
==7431==    by 0x4016A7: boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator<<(char const*) (formatting_ostream.hpp:392)
==7431==    by 0x4011F6: main (test.cpp:4)
```

On this laptop I have Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and boost 1.58.

Everything I am working with has been installed with `apt` without using any external repo.
The same code (and, in general, `boost::log`) works without any issues on similar configurations.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this issue, as the problem seems to lie in the boost or system libraries.

Comment: Passes fine on Ubuntu 17.10 with Boost 1.62.

Comment: It actually works well also on another computer of mine, which has a pretty similar configuration to my laptop. I'm sure it's not a problem of boost *per se* (many more users would have complained if that was the case). My question is more about "how can I understand what's going on and what can I do to troubleshoot it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have ABI issues, most likely due to mixed versions of the shared library, or due compiling with incompatible compilation flags.

Comment: I was using g++-4.9 while (I guess?) boost libs were linked against g++-5's libraries. Uninstalling g++-4.9 did the trick. Thanks!